# Sync default register with "r" register in Vim

Tags: vim

I'd like to use `ctrl-r r` to insert the last deleted/yanked text, just to be a bit more efficient than `ctrl-r "`.

I think I need to use something involving `autocmd TextYankPost`, so far I have:

`autocmd TextYankPost * insertIntoRegisterR(v:event['regcontents'])`

For the imaginary function `insertIntoRegisterR`, I don't know how to insert something into a register in the context of vimscript, and google isn't being particularly helpful.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: See `:help getreg()` and `:help setreg()`.

Comment: Perhaps a simple way to accomplish this would be `inoremap <C-r>r <C-r>"`

Comment: @filbranden nice, I figured something like that would introduce lag when putting in other commands, so I hadn't considered it, but it seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: @romainl ah I see, thanks! If I go the autocmd route now I know. Those were hard to find.

Comment: @Woahdae, no they are not hard to find. `getreg()` is mentioned under `:help TextYankPost`.